# Stop NodeJS remotely

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, node.js

I'm working on a NodeJS project where a PHP server will have control over starting and stopping a NodeJS socket server. The server will be started by a remote call via PHP however I am unsure of how to go about stopping a remote NodeJS server, as all answers I have found simply tell me to hit CTRL-C, which is not an option in this case. Does anyone know how to cause an end event in a tidy manner? Is there an event that can fine or is the best I can do to throw an exception?

Comment: Did you try `proc_open` and `proc_close`?

Comment: Definitely like the answer, but I should add that the NodeJS server itself may not be on the same machine as the PHP script, will add that point to the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always expose a route that calls `process.exit();`

[Node API Docs: process.exit](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/process.html#process.exit)

Comment: Accepting this, as it allows me to get it done with Node rather than any platform-specific method!

Answer (score 1):

I'd setup a kickstart script for your nodejs app in /etc/init.d then [start|reset|stop] from the command line. If it's on a remote machine you should look into your php app using passwordless SSH to start/stop remotely.

Comment: You might want to have that passwordless login be to an account with no write access to any data and then setup `/etc/sudoers` to allow that account to run the `/etc/init.d` script as root. this would allow the stop command to be `ssh user@host sudo /etc/init.d/script stop`. This would prevent cascading security failure.